# « C'est pourquoi » : coordination ou subordination ?

Tags: grammaire, conjonctions, subordonnées, coordination

Quelquefois je ne comprends pas la différence entre la coordination et subordination.

J'ai lu que *c'est pourquoi* est une conjonction de coordination.

> Il est malade, c'est pourquoi il reste chez lui.

*Il est malade* et *c'est pourquoi il reste chez lui* seraient donc deux propositions coordonnées, mais je dirais que *c'est pourquoi il reste chez lui* est une proposition subordonnée circonstancielle de conséquence. A mon avis, *c'est pourquoi* est sûrement subordonnée à la proposition principale parce qu'elle ne peut pas fonctionner toute seule...
Tout comme par exemple ici : *Je pense que c'est une bonne idée*. (subordination)

Quelqu'un pourrait-il m'aider à comprendre ?

Comment: @Fólkvangr Je ne suis pas d'accord... "il est malade" est la raison pour laquelle il reste chez lui. Donc "il reste chez lui" est la conséquence.

Answer (score 2):

**C'est pourquoi** est bien une conjonction de coordination. Elle coordonne les propositions:

> *Il est malade*

et

> *il reste chez lui*

[Plus de détails](https://www.espacefrancais.com/les-conjonctions-de-coordination-et-de-subordination/)

Answer (score 1):

« C'est pourquoi » n'est pas une conjonction de coordination. Il s'agit dans cette phrase de deux propositions indépendantes, qui sont reliées  par une relation de conséquence; « C'est … lui. » ne fonctionne pas seul sémantiquement mais seule la grammaire nous intéresse et de ce point de vue-là c'est une proposition qui fonctionne toute seule.

> (TLFi) Le temps est de nouveau complètement couvert. C'est aussi pourquoi sans doute j'ai mal dormi.

*dialogue*

- -- Le thermomètre indique une température en dessous de zéro.
  -- C'est pourquoi il y a des glaçons sur la vitre.

Il ne s'agit pas donc d'une principale et de sa subordonnée mais de deux indépendantes.

ADDITION Pour qui n'est pas familier avec le critère de détermination des propositions indépendantes, j'ajoute les détails suivants (suivant la suggestion de user **Fólkvangr**).

Le principe général dit que si l'on peut réécrire une partie de phrase telle qu'elle est, sans omettre un mot en son début qui n'aurait pas de place dans la proposition qui précède et que le résultat est une phrase grammaticalement correcte alors c'est une proposition indépendante dans la phrase où on la trouve initialement; comme le nom l'indique elle peut exister par elle-même, n'a pas besoin de support.
Un point à garder à l'esprit est la nécessité de petits ajustements ; trois sortes sont considérées ci-dessous, mais il peut en exister quelques autres.

1/ Les parties de phrase sont reliées par une conjonction de coordination ; alors on supprime tout simplement la conjonction et on ne cherche pas à la joindre à une quelconque partie de la phrase.

2/ Il y a une ellipse du sujet (sujet non répété) ; alors on introduit le sujet ;

- Ils ne font pas le travail, ne font rien comme on le leur montre, et même, ne font rien du tout.
- ==> Ils ne font pas le travail. _ Ils ne font rien comme on le leur montre. _ Ils ne font même rien du tout.

3/ Il y a un adverbe mal placé ; alors on le change de position en conservant le sens. Un exemple de cela se trouve au « 2/ » (même).

Plusieurs modifications de la sorte mentionnée sont aussi possibles, comme on le voit à l'exemple « 2/ ».

Comment: @Fólkvangr Ce commentaire est passé à travers mes révisions, je ne le vois que maintenant ; où est-ce qu'il faudrait ajouter « Parce qu'il est malade. »  ?

Comment: @Fólkvangr Write down clearly what you'd like to read and tell me where to put it; if I agree I'll make an addition.

Comment: @Fólkvangr Oui, je comprend cela, sauf bien sûr, dans une réponse (Pourquoi n'est-il pas venu ? Parce qu'il est malade.); mais comment dois-je introduire l'idée dans mon texte et où ? Quel est ce raisonnement que semblez voir ?

Comment: @Fólkvangr Je vois maintenant… essayer de démontrer que « c'est pourquoi » est une locution conjonctive de subordination et non une locution conjonctive  de coordination ; vous avez amorcé cela dans les commentaires et je crois que vous pouvez en faire une réponse ; la possibilité de pouvoir vous exprimer de façon complète dans une réponse me donnerait, ainsi qu'à d'autres, une opportunité de mieux apprécier ce que vous, personnellement, avez précisément en tête.